# Should I use "or" or "nor" or "neither" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, negation

> I won't talk to my boyfriend anymore. Or/nor/neither to you.

I often get confused about this. How to make the distinction?

Comment: You could say *Or to you, Nor to you,* or *Or to you either*, but if you want to use ***neither*** it would have to replace the existing negation as *I will talk to neither my boyfriend nor/or you anymore*, which is a bit clunky / formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to gussy it up a bit to use some of those.

> I won't talk to my boyfriend anymore. Or to you.

Is fine, if a bit casual. If you want to use "nor" or neither, you need a different structure, like

> I won't talk to my boyfriend anymore, nor/neither will I talk to you.

Comment: So when should I use "or" vr "nor/neither"?

Comment: Up to you. "nor" is a little bit fancy and may sound strange to people, but any of those will work, and all convey an identical meaning.